# Python interpreter locked/freezing while trying to run pygetwindow as a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to learn how to use threading and specifically `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` this is because I need to return a `numpy.array` from a function I want to run concurrently.

The end goal is to have one process running a video loop of an application, while another process does object detection and GUI interactions. The `result()` keyword from the [concurrent.futures library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) allows me to do this.

The issue is my code runs once, and then seems to lock up. I'm actually unsure what happens as when I step through it in the debugger it runs once, then the debugger goes blank and I literally cannot step through and no error is thrown.

The code appears to lock up on the line: `notepadWindow = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Notepad')[0]`

I get exactly one loop, the `print` statement prints once the loop restarts and then it halts at `pygetwindow`

I don't know much about the GIL but I have tried using the `max_workers=1` argument on `ThreadPoolExecutor()` which doesn't make a difference either way and I was under the impression `concurrent.futures` allows me to bypass the lock.

How do I run `videoLoop` as a single thread making sure to return `DetectionWindow` every iteration?

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pygetwindow

def videoLoop():
    notepadWindow = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Notepad')[0]
    x1 = notepadWindow.left
    y1 = notepadWindow.top
    height = notepadWindow.height
    width = notepadWindow.width
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img)
    DetectionWindow= cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return DetectionWindow

def f1():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        f1 = executor.submit(videoLoop)
        notepadWindow = f1.result()
        cv.imshow("Video Loop", notepadWindow)
        cv.waitKey(1)
        print(f1.result())

while True:
    f1()
```

Comment: Not sure that you want the *while True* here. You'll be creating huge numbers of ThreadPoolExecutors in a very tight loop. Also, I'm not sure what will happen if you try calling *f1.result()* twice on the same Future object. Lastly, you may need to check if *pygetwindow* is known to be thread safe

Comment: Interestingly if I remove the *while True* it runs once and then closes rather than locks up. My IDE was getting oddly slow so that makes sense now. Why would calling `result` twice on one object cause an issue? Not arguing I just haven't seen anything online about it either way! And any idea how I check something is a known safe thread? Thank you for the reply @OlvinRoght

Comment: I'm not saying that calling *result* twice **will** cause a problem but you already have the value so why not *print(notepadWindow)*. Of course it will only run once if you call f1() once. What do you actually want to happen? Please edit your question to clarify the functional requirement. There's nothing in the documentation (that I can see) regarding thread safety. Bear in mind though that this module is "under development" yet hasn't been modified in over a year so may not be very reliable. It's also not portable. Lastly, what do you think will happen if Notepad isn't actually running?

Comment: I've updated the original question with my functional requirement (I think). If notepad isn't running it throws an expected error (which is alright for now I'm just trying to figure out how to run VideoLoop as a thread). What does not portable mean in python terms?

Comment: "portable" means that your code would be runnable on any platform (*nix, Windows) subject to the Python version itself being compatible. *pygetwindow* is Windows only and therefore not portable in this sense

Comment: Ah right, so the same as normal "portable" I wasn't sure if this meant something different for python. That seems ok, only need it to run on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ThreadPoolExecutor won't help you an awful lot here, if you want a continuous stream of frames.

Here's a reworking of your code that uses a regular old `threading.Thread` and puts frames (and their capture timestamps, since this is asynchronous) in a `queue.Queue` you can then read in another (or the main) thread.

The thread has an otherwise infinite loop that can be stopped by setting the thread's `exit_signal`.

(I didn't test this, since I'm presently on a Mac, so there may be typos or other problems.)

```
import queue
import time

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import threading
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pygetwindow


def do_capture():
    notepadWindow = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle("Notepad")[0]
    x1 = notepadWindow.left
    y1 = notepadWindow.top
    height = notepadWindow.height
    width = notepadWindow.width
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    return cv.cvtColor(np.array(haystack_img), cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


class VideoCaptureThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, result_queue: queue.Queue) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.exit_signal = threading.Event()
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self) -> None:
        while not self.exit_signal.wait(0.05):
            try:
                result = do_capture()
                self.result_queue.put((time.time(), result))
            except Exception as exc:
                print(f"Failed capture: {exc}")


def process_frames(result_queue: queue.Queue):
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 5:  # Run for five seconds
        frame = result_queue.get()
        print(frame)


def main():
    result_queue = queue.Queue()
    thread = VideoCaptureThread(result_queue=result_queue)
    thread.start()
    process_frames(result_queue)
    thread.exit_signal.set()
    thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this! I get a continuous stream of frames and this runs independently in it's own thread correctly but I can't "return" or use those frames outside of this thread.

Comment: You read them from the queue like the example does...

Comment: Can I read them from the queue in another function?

Comment: Of course. `main()` is another function in the example here, anyway.

Comment: I think then all I need is `result_queue = queue.Queue()` and `frame = result_queue.get()` to grab those in another function right? I don't need to start the thread again as it's already running

Comment: You'll need to pass the same queue you've passed to the thread to the other function; you shouldn't construct a new one. You could also make it a global variable if it makes it easier.

Comment: Don't I need to define the variable per function and I can't return frame outside of main(). How do I access the same queue without re-defining it? Only with a global function?

Comment: I don't know how your program is structured, but I edited my answer a bit to show how a second function could work. You just pass in the `result_queue`.

Comment: I think I understand what you're doing there! Thank you, just one last question. If I'm generating the frames with one funciton, and processing them with a second does it matter which function starts first? Or does FIFO mean it'll just start processing when it can i.e. the processing function will grab frames whenever the generating function has them ready

Comment: Well, the thread needs to be started before you enter a blocking function (such as one with an infinite `while` loop), but `result_queue.get()` will block until there are frames in the queue, so in that sense it doesn't matter.

Comment: Does that mean I can't run two `while` loops at once?

Comment: Well, a single thread runs a single function at a time.