# How do I return a value outside of a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to return a continuous stream of frames to perform object detection. I want this continuous stream of frames to run at the same time as a number of other GUI interactions and detections, I tried using both `concurrent.futures` and `multiprocessing` and ran into road-blocks with both pointed out by members of stack. I'm now trying to use `threading` to achieve this.

The below code will correctly return a continuous stream of frames and display those frames.

I can print and interact with those frames from within `main` but I can't seem to return `frame` to use it outside of `main`

How do I return `main` outside of my thread?

```
def videoLoop():
    # Grab window and find size and crop it
    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Notepad')[0]
    x1 = window.left
    y1 = window.top
    height = window.height
    width = window.width
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    # Actual Video Loop, cropped down to the specific window,
    # resized to 1/2 size, and converted to BGR for OpenCV
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    crop = haystack_img.crop((750,30,1150,78))
    haystack_img_np = np.array(crop)
    haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.imshow("Detection", haystack)
    cv.waitKey(1)
    return haystack


class VideoCaptureThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, result_queue: queue.Queue) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.exit_signal = threading.Event()
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self) -> None:
        while not self.exit_signal.wait(0.05):
            try:
                result = videoLoop()
                self.result_queue.put(result)
            except Exception as exc:
                print(f"Failed capture: {exc}")

def main():
    result_queue = queue.Queue()
    thread = VideoCaptureThread(result_queue=result_queue)
    thread.start()
    while True:
        frame = result_queue.get()
        print(frame)
        return frame


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



def shipDetection(image_list, threshold, haystack, a):
    # Object Detection
    for x in range (0, a):
        for i in image_list:
            cv.imshow("Ship Detection", haystack)
            cv.waitKey(1)
            needle_img = i[0]
            needle_name = i[1]
            sliced_name = needle_name.split("\\")[-1]
            result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack, needle_img, cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED)

            # Get the best match position
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
            percentage_max_val = round(max_val*100, 2)

            # Define top left and bottom right and threshold
            (H, W) = i[0].shape[:2] 
            top_left = max_loc
            bottom_right = (top_left[0] + W, top_left[1] + H)

            # If something has been detected click keep looking code
            if max_val >= threshold:
                cv.rectangle(haystack, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
                cv.imshow("Ship Detection", haystack)
                cv.waitKey(1)
                keep_looking(sliced_name, percentage_max_val)
                print(sliced_name, percentage_max_val)
                return True
        return False
```

[image]

Comment: Re, "I can't seem to return `frame`..." What do you mean. What happens when you try? You've showed us code that puts frames in a queue, but it sounds like you are having trouble _using_ those frames. Where is the code that is supposed to use the frames?

Comment: @SolomonSlow for context this is a previous post where someone helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71233954/python-interpreter-locked-freezing-while-trying-to-run-pygetwindow-as-a-thread?noredirect=1#comment125914665_71233954

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, because I don't understand the question yet, but I can't put code snippets into a comment. I have two comments:

---

**(1)** This is a common pattern in Python code:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

Whenever a Python source code file is executed as a script, the global variable, `__name__` will equal `"__main__"`, and the `...` will be executed.  If the same file is loaded as a package, `__name__` will equal the name of the package, and the `...` will *not* be executed.

If *your* code is executed as a script, it will call `main()` and then it will *throw away the return value.* You say you are having trouble returning a value from `main()`, but if you want a return value from `main()`, then why do you throw away the return value at the call site?

*Is* your code meant to be executed as a script? or is it meant to be used as a package, and is `main()` merely test code? If it's test code, then what is the test supposed to prove? If it's a script, then what is the script supposed to do? (e.g., `print()` *all* of the frames?)

---

**(2)** This can't be right:

```py
while True:
    ...
    return frame
```

You put an unconditional `return` statement inside a loop. The body of that loop can never be executed more than one time because the very first iteration will always `return` from `main()`.

So, why did you try to make it loop? What were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've updated with the function where I need `frame`. `frame` is needed as my `haystack` in the `shipDetection` function. It's the detection area I'm using for `matchTemplate`. At the moment the `while True: frame = result_queue.get()` is correctly outputting a stream of frames, if I dump a `print(frame)` at the end of the while true (before the return) I get the correct output to my terminal. I just need to pass that output into my `shipDetection` function and months of learning is finally working!

Comment: Re, "...the `while True: ...` is correctly outputting a stream..." Are you sure that the code shown in your question is the same as the code that you are running? The `while True` loop in the `main()` function in your question can not possibly print more than one frame.

Comment: Re, "...shipDetection..." OK, So, I understand that you want the `shipDetection(..., haystack,...)` to be called with `haystack` equal to the `frame` that your `main()` function pulls from the queue—the same as the `result` that your `VideoCaptureThread.run()` puts in to the queue, the same as the `haystack` that your `videoLoop()` function returns. Do I understand that correctly? If so, then why don't you simply _call_ `shipDetection(..., frame,...)` from your `main()` loop? Am I still missing some part of the problem?

Comment: It's an exact copy paste, I get the im.show coming up showing the video stream. I just need those frames available elsewhere. `while True: frame=result_queue.get()` is in the def main() function. My thinking initially was, to have the frames output constantly and use them as and when needed for detection rather than running detection constantly. I was having issues with the very first object being detected, all subsequent detection seems to be working correctly but the first one was never being detected. (I'm checking for a lot of images).

Comment: I've updated the OP with a gif of what's currently happening. It's definitely looping more than once. And I don't *need* things to execute as a script, that's just the only way I've been able to get things to work, trying to learn by project work.

Comment: @mak47, I don't think I can help you. Sorry.